# AssertJ and Groovy force type?

Tags: groovy, types, assertj

I'm learning Groovy as I develop this project so I'm not sure of my ground.

I have an assertion like so:

```
assertThat( spyCH.getLoopCount() ).isEqualTo( 1 )
```

There is no explicit method `getLoopCount()`, but there is an instance variable `loopCount` in the `CH` class. Groovy automatically creates getters and setters.

I declared `CH` instance variable `loopCount` like so

```
def loopCount // i.e. "type undefined" (as yet)
```

Actually this got to the value 11. And I got the following fail:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<1[]> but was:<1[1]>
```

Obviously the result is being interpreted as a String. I then changed the instance variable to

```
int loopCount
```

... but I still get the same String comparison

Then I changed the test line to:

```
assertThat( (int)spyCH.getLoopCount() ).isEqualTo( (int)1 )
```

... but I still get the same fail line.

Is there anyone out there who knows how you can force AssertJ to do an `int`/`Integer` comparison in Groovy? (NB they're the same in Groovy: it has no primitive values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JUnit comparison failure only shows the difference between the values **represented** as `String` but the `isEqualTo` assertion compares values according to their type ending up doing something like `actual.equals(expected)` (or `actual == expected) for primitive types`).

If you execute `assertThat( spyCH.getLoopCount() ).isEqualTo( 456 )` the error will look like:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[1]> but was:<[456]>
```

Again a textual difference is shown but values are not compared as String.

When writing `assertThat(value)`, java (and Groovy I believe) will use the best matching `assertThat` methods, if `value` is declared or inferred as an `int` it will use [`assertThat(int actual)`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/Assertions.html#assertThat-int-), if the type is not specified then `assertThat(Object actual)` is picked.

Hope that clarifies things a bit

Comment: Yes that clarifies it. Thanks.